# Resolving DNS names on non-domain PCs

Tags: networking, dns, domain

I have recently added an Active Directory controller and DNS to a 2012 R2 server on our network on **192.168.0.1** and added an A record for Server1 to **192.168.0.2**.

I've assigned PCs in my test environment to a Primary DNS **192.168.0.1** only (no secondary).

If the PC is attached to the domain, they will resolve Server1 to **192.168.0.2** correctly.

PCs not attached to the domain will not.  They will, however, resolve Server1.mydomain.com correctly.

Is there a way to configure this so that non-domain PCs can resolve Server1 to the correct IP address without having to use the FQDN?

Comment: So these PC's not attached to the domain, are set to use the domain server, as their DNS Server?  This question cannot be answered without the answer to that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have windows append the suffix when you don't type in a FQDN, like so:

Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections > Right-click the network adapter > Properties > Double-click TCP/IPv4 or TCP/IPv6 > Advanced > In the "DNS" Tab:

[image: Domain_Suffix]